# ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, ora-01427

I have query like this:

```
select bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10 as kode, 
bb10.NAME_SEKTOR_10 as sektor10,
(
    select count(*) as HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 
    from bbcust_debitur_dev 
    where HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 = bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10
    and STATUS = 2 
    group by HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10
) as total_sek_10,
(
    select  sum( distinct bbcd.baki_debet) as baki_debet
    from bbcust_cashloan_dev bbcd, bbcust_debitur_dev bdd
    where bbcd.row_id = bdd.row_id 
    and bdd.HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 = bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10
    and bbcd.status =1 and bdd.status=2
    group by bdd.row_id
) as total_rek_10
from BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV bb10;
```

I get an error

> ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row

But before i just have data like this, i don't have any error.
This query didn't have any errors.

```
select bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10 as kode, 
bb10.NAME_SEKTOR_10 as sektor10,
(
    select count(*) as HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 
    from bbcust_debitur_dev 
    where HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 = bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10
    and STATUS = 2 
    group by HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10
) as total_sek_10
from BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV bb10;
```

And the result like this :

[image]

The stucture of bbcust_cash_loan like this:

[image]

For structure of database is : `bbcust_debitur_dev` have relation with `BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV` and `bbcust_cashloan_dev`.

I want to calculate every value in `bbcust_cashloan_dev`, but I need to know all data in `BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV`. That's why I join all data, so I get total value from `bbcust_cashloan_dev` where data in `BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV`.

Can you tell me how to fix my query?

Comment: Just remove group by clause from your sub-query. Group by clause is not needed here.

Comment: @Md.ShamimAlMamun can you post on the answer question, i will vote for you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.......

```
select bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10 as kode, 
bb10.NAME_SEKTOR_10 as sektor10,
(
    select count(*) as HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 
    from bbcust_debitur_dev 
    where HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 = bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10
    and STATUS = 2 
    ) as total_sek_10,
(
    select  sum( distinct bbcd.baki_debet) as baki_debet
    from bbcust_cashloan_dev bbcd, bbcust_debitur_dev bdd
    where bbcd.row_id = bdd.row_id 
    and bdd.HUBBNI_SEKTOR_EKONOMI10 = bb10.ID_SEKTOR_10
    and bbcd.status =1 and bdd.status=2
    ) as total_rek_10
from BBCUST_SEKTOR_10_DEV bb10;
```

There is a possibility that `group by bdd.row_id` returns more than one row. Without knowing your business it is impossible to give suggestion.